# How to model bounded contexts in ASPNET WebAPI

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design

I am trying to model the equivalent of a bounded context as outlined by Fowler  [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html), using WebAPI endpoint(s).

Basically, I have a "Contact" DTO which is representative of a CRM centric view of a customer.
A sales or a billing centric view of a "Contact" might be different, involving querying attributes from multiple tables to construct their view of "Contact".

In WebAPI, typically there would be a "Contacts" controller that would return a collection of "ContactDTOs".

What is the best way to support the above scenario in a clean, RESTful way using WebAPI?

Some thoughts below:

a. Create a separate action for each use case, and return a different DTO such as  "SalesContactDTO", "BillingContactDTO" in the ContactsController

> ```
> http://hostname/api/SalesContacts
> http://hostname/api/BillingContacts
> http://hostname/api/CRMContacts
> ```

b. Create separate controllers in which the Get() return the appropriate DTO.

> ```
> "SalesContactsController"
> "BillingContactsConroller"
> ```

c. Create a single "ContactsController", set a "request header" that indicates 
    which Contact "view" to return:

```
   public ContactDTOBase[] Get()
      {
         //read request header
         var contactType = Request.GetHeaders("whatever");
         switch(contactType)
         {
             case "Billing":{ return new SalesContactDTO[]{};}
             case "Sales": { return new BillingContactDTO[]{};}
         }
         return CRMContact[]{};
      }
```

Sound off in the comments :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would almost certainly create either different controllers or more likely, entirely separate projects

http://sales-hostname/api/contacts

http://billing-hostname/api/contacts

http://crm-hostname/api/contacts

If you try and combine into a single controller, using either method 1 or method 3 above, you're going to end up with it being responsible for too much. You'll end up with having to change it anytime *any* bounded context changes, not to mention any dependencies the controller will need.

Comment: I considered doing just that, but imagine now you have multiple entities  in play for which you need bounded contexts.The issue is that this could quickly lead to a proliferation of projects for use cases where there are even relatively minor variations in the structure of the entities. This proves unwieldy and a bit harder to maintain over time.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about read models / reporting / queries? I'd be surprised if you had a proliferation of Contacts - how many bounded contexts will you have? i'm not suggesting a new project per aggregate.

Comment: Contacts is just a trivial example, any of the common entities in an enterprise is game, "Account", "Product","Opportunity". Depending on the context these entities are used in could require a different "shape" or "model" in that context, Read (GET) is the most common scenario

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel IMO tomliversidge's solution is the way to go. A Bounded Context is not just a use case. It's not an Aggregate either. You shouldn't have that many. Plus, it's a good idea to make them independently deployable (which isn't the case if they're all in the same web app).

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel Both the commentators have good points, are you understanding the implications of what a Bounded Context is? In each Bounded Context, each Contact would not only have its own model, but it would have its own table or collection when persisted (maybe several separate SQL databases).  These Bounded Contexts would exist as completely separate system, where something like Web API would be used to allow the separate systems to communicate.

Comment: "would have its own table", that's the point I'm trying to wrap my head around.Is it a mandate to have separate table/db for having a different representation of an entity?For instance, the conceptual representation of a "Contact" in one case could be a subset of attributes from  the "Contact" table,in another case,might be attributes from "Contact" table joined with other relational tables in the same DB.Depending on the context (billing/sales etc.) you might want to return different representations. Is this best modeled by having a different webapi for such scenario?